# What is the difference between `blocktrans` and `blocktranslate`? Between `trans` and `translate`?

Tags: django

What is the difference between these two lines of code in a Django template?

```html
{% blocktrans %}Example{% endblocktrans %}
{% blocktranslate %}Example{% endblocktranslate %}
```

Likewise, what is the difference between these two lines of code in a Django template?

```html
{% trans "Example" %}
{% translate "Example" %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. `{% blocktrans %}` is equivalent to `{% blocktranslate %}`, it's just an alias. Likewise, `{% trans %}` is equivalent to `{% translate %}`.

Comment: True, there is no difference.  The tag was changed from `trans` to `translate` in Django 3.1 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag).  Look at the bottom of that section.